# Python - Download file over HTTP and detect filetype automatically

Tags: python, http

I want download a file via HTTP, but all the examples online involve fetching the data and then putting it in a local file. The problem with this is that you need to explicitly set the filetype of the local file.

I want to download a file but I won't know the filetype of what I'm downloading.

This is what I currently have:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(fetch_url,output.csv)
```

But if I download, say a XML file it will be CSV. Is there anyway to get python to detect the file that I get sent from a URL like: http://asassaassa.com/assaas?abc=123

Say the above URL gives me an XML I want python to detect that.

Comment: Do you have control over the server?  As in, does the server allow you to either query or set the filetype to download?  There's really no such thing as generic "filetype detection", besides trying to parse the file as several formats, or looking for a specific header format.  Usually, the download url would include the file extension, which is an easy way to determine the filetype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) to detect file type. It can be installed via "pip install python-magic".

I assume you are using python 2.7 since you are calling urlretreieve. The example is geared to 2.7, but it is easily adapted.

This is a working example:

```
import mimetypes # Detects mimetype
import magic  # Uses magic numbers to detect file type, and does so much better than the built in mimetypes
import urllib # Your library
import os     # for renaming your file
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True) 
output = "output" # Your file name without extension
urllib.urlretrieve("https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/mimetypes.html", output) # This is just an example url
mimes = mime.from_file(output) # Get mime type
ext = mimetypes.guess_all_extensions(mimes)[0] # Guess extension
os.rename(output, output+ext) # Rename file
```